# What's wrong with this regex? MSVC <regex> accepts but gcc <regex> and <regex.h> reject

Tags: regex, visual-c++, gcc, g++

Here's the code that runs fine with MSVC

```
std::regex r;
//r = "setdata\\(\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\",[^\\\"]*\\\"([^\\\"]*)";
r = "setdata\\(";
```

and it is also parsed fine by online validators (of course when removing \ escapes).

But with g++ 4.6 it throws regex_error. I know that its regex support is not finished so I tried <regex.h>:

```
char buf[1024];
regex_t regex;
//int reti = regcomp(&regex, "setdata\\(\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\",[^\\\"]*\\\"([^\\\"]*)", 0);
int reti = regcomp(&regex, "setdata\\(", 0);
regerror(reti, &regex, buf, 1024);
```

it reports "Unmatched ( or \("

UPDATE: here's what I found:

Unfortunately the native platforms provide Posix regular expressions support that contains bugs and/or violates the specification. This is especially true for the GNU C library (GLIBC) used by Linux distributions (c) http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Regex_Posix#regex-posix_Bugs

Can this be one of those POSIX regex library bugs?

UPDATE: Thanks to the comment, I simplified pattern, seems like gcc looks for a pair for the escaped \( which doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: I show five parenthesis in your expression. Is that a typo or the actual issue?

Comment: The first of them is escaped because it's just a literal. But you're right this is the problem.

Comment: Oh, this. <regex.h> is a different crop of regular expressions with a slightly different syntax. Try using `REG_EXTENDED`.

Comment: REG_EXTENDED helped with regex_t, thanks (why don't you make it an answer? ;-), while std::regex seems to be buggy, unless you know a similar flag for it ;-)

Comment: The `std::regex` included with `gcc` is way beyond just buggy, well into completely broken territory. A *few* simple regexes work, but it doesn't even try to implement anything but a few of the most trivial cases.